# Image cover height of screen and sticky footer clinch

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, sticky-footer

I have an image I want to cover the entire screen, before a user starts scrolling. I am struggling to combine this with a sticky footer implemented through flexbox.

I'm wrapping all the content inside a container, and including the CSS  "flex: 1 0 auto" to make it grow to fill the space. The footer has the property "flex-shrink: 0".

The issue is that the content wrapper has a height larger than 100% of the screen height, as it contains a lot of content. Therefore, I can not  set the height of the container containing the image to 100%, as the image will then cover more than the screen height.

Any suggestions for how to solve this issue?

Markup:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="home-container">
      <div class="home-content-container">
        Image
      </div>
      <div class="flex-container" id="copywriting-container">
        Blah blah
      </div>
    </div>

   <footer class="navbar footer-navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container footer-container">
       Blah Blah
    </div>
   </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

∕∕ Content wrapper
.home-container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

// Image container
.home-content-container {
  background-image: image-url("blue_sky_copy5.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

 // footer
.footer-navbar {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of body to 100vh, so that it fills the screen. then you can set "overflow" property of the .home-container to "scroll" or "auto".

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

∕∕ Content wrapper
.home-container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

// Image container
.home-content-container {
  background-image: image-url("blue_sky_copy5.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

 // footer
.footer-navbar {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Note that i have set the box-sizing property of body to "border-box" to ignore the padding and make it fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Setting height of home-content-container to 100vh fixed the issue.